# Seaching L figure curve by OSMNX

Tags: python, osmnx

I search for "the L figure curve" in Shibya, Tokyo by OSMNX, Python.
This L figure curve means that the corner connects two streets(nodes) and the angle degree of the corner is between  90<x<145. But If I set it by myself, it became an error.
In the other case, I set just x<145, it appeared on the list, but the angles are 14 degrees. why....
If you know how to find it, please tell me.
Thanks.

```
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from colorspacious import cspace_converter

ward_names = [
    "Shibuya",
]

graph = ox.graph_from_place(ward_names, network_type="drive")

nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=True, edges=False)
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=False, edges=True)

print("Number of nodes:", len(nodes))
print("Number of edges:", len(edges))
ox.plot_graph(graph)

gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph)

gdf_nodes.head()

import math

# Calculate the angle for each node
gdf_nodes['angle'] = gdf_nodes.apply(lambda row: math.degrees(math.atan2(row['y'], row['x'])), axis=1)

# Filter nodes with street_count equal to 2
selected_nodes_2 = gdf_nodes[gdf_nodes["street_count"] == 2]

# Filter nodes based on the angle criteria (90 to 135 degrees)
#If I select angle more than 90, as (selected_nodes_2['angle'] >= 90), it does't work. I think I mistook my code. coz this angle almost 14.
l_curve = selected_nodes_2[(selected_nodes_2['angle'] <= 145)]   

l_curve
```